# How to create a std::tuple which containins members from a vector specified by a tuple of indexes?

Tags: c++, stl, variadic-templates

I have a std::vector of some values, for example `std::vector<std::string> v = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};` and then I have a tuple of numbers created from a parameter pack (i.e. it may have any size). How can I create a tuple of the vector members (tuple of std::string here) which uses the indexes tuple as indexes to the vector? For example if the tuple of indexes has values 0, 3, 1, then the result should be same as I wrote `auto result = std::make_tuple("a", "d", "b");`. I am using Visual Studio 2015.

edit: clarified the tuple of indexes

Comment: what did you try? Actually I dont see the problem. Simply iterate through the tuple and add the corresponding elements to the output tuple

Comment: btw why are you using `tuple`s when it is all `string` / all integers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
template <typename C, typename Tuple, int... Is>
auto project_impl(const C& c, const Tuple& indices, 
                  std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>) {
  return std::make_tuple(c[std::get<Is>(indices)]...);
}

template <typename C, typename Tuple>
auto project(const C& c, const Tuple& indices) {
  return project_impl(c, indices,
    std::make_integer_sequence<int, std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>());
}
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/FABIM13877)